# azure documentdb trigger for push notification

Tags: triggers, azure-cosmosdb

I need to call push notifications from my trigger but I need to do the following:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var notificationHubService = azure.createNotificationHubService("","");
```

But I am getting the following:

> executing Javascript. Exception = ReferenceError: 'require' is
>   undefined

Is there another way to accomplish this, can I import node.js libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I've developed the ability to include some npm modules from inside DocumentDB server-side scripts in [documentdb-utils](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils#support-for-require-in-server-side-scripts). It's tested with UDFs and sprocs, but it should work for triggers. It doesn't work for all npm modules though, so ymmv.

That said, I don't think that's your only problem. As far as I know, the normal ways of calling out from javascript code (XHR, node.js HTTP.request, etc.) are not enabled for DocumentDB server-side scripts. Without some way to make an outbound call, I don't think there is any way to do what you want.

I have a similar situation. My work-around until DocumentDB has some sort of message bus or pub/sub, I queue up messages in DocumentDB documents and poll them.

Comment: Quick question, how do you go about and install this up on azure so  I can pull into the trigger and give it a whirl?

Comment: What do you mean, "install this up on azure"? What environment are you using? .NET? Since DocumentDB executes JavaScript, most of my development is in node.js although I have some examples for how to use the output in .NET. The trick is to install and use my node.js based tools for generating sprocs, UDFs, and triggers, then take that output of that as a string that you can send in as a server-side script to DocumentDB using whatever technology you want.